# Turn a string literal type to a literal value

Tags: string, typescript

In TypeScript, we can have string literal types that allow us to do things like:

```
type HelloString = "Hello";
```

This lets me define something like a string enum as follows:

```
namespace Literals {
    export type One = "one";
    export type Two = "two";
}
```

And then I can define a union:

```
type Literal = Literals.One | Literals.Two;
```

Is there a way to extract the unique value of `Literals.One` as the type `Literals.One`?

The reason for this, is that when I define a function like this:

```
function doSomething(literal : Literal) {

}
```

I'd really love to do the following:

```
doSomething(Literals.One);
```

But I can't. I have to write:

```
doSomething("one");
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can have types and values with the same name inside a namespace, so you can define constants for those values:

```
namespace Literals {
    export type One = "one";
    export type Two = "two";
    export const One: One = "one";
    export const Two: Two = "two";
}

const s: Literals.One = Literals.One;
console.log(s);
```

There is a [proposal on GitHub for string enums](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3192), they suggest the current best solution is the example above.

Answer (score 6):

Turning a string literal type to a literal value is possible with custom transformers (https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/13940), which is available in typescript@next.

Please look into my npm package, [ts-transformer-enumerate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-transformer-enumerate).

Example usage:

```
// The signature of `enumerate` here is `function enumerate<T extends string>(): { [K in T]: K };`
import { enumerate } from 'ts-transformer-enumerate';

type Colors = 'green' | 'yellow' | 'red';
const Colors = enumerate<Colors>();

console.log(Colors.green); // 'green'
console.log(Colors.yellow); // 'yellow'
console.log(Colors.red); // 'red'
```